# NO FUNCIONA EL ECHO EN PHPMAILER

Tags: php, script, phpmailer, echo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]El problema que he encontrado, es que el echo en mi código no muestra la frase "mensaje enviado" pero SI funciona todo el código y me llega el correo sin ningún problema... asi que cuando le doy enviar MUESTRA UNA PAGINA CON TODO EL CODIGO DE ENVIO DE PHP. TODAS LAS INSTRUCCIONES QUE SE LLEVARON A CABO PARA EL ENVIO.

Así que intente con un windows.location dentro de un  en echo para mostrar "mensaje enviado" y redirigir al index pero cuando hace esta redirección al index.html, SIGUE APARECIENDO ESE CODIGO PHP PERO AHORA durante 2 segundos... ¿cómo podría hacer para que la redirección fuera inmediata? o al menos, ¿no se mostrara dicho código? O..si existe una manera de que SOBRE EL MISMO FOMULARIO SOLO MUESTRE LA ALERTA DE "MENSAJE ENVIADO".

```html
<?php
//Load composer's autoloader
require_once('Mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
$asunto = $_POST["asunto"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$body =  "Nombre: " . $nombre . "<br>Correo: " . $correo . "<br>Mensaje: " . $mensaje. "<br>Teléfono: " . $telefono;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;// TCP port to connect to
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username ='micorreo@gmail.com'; //Email para enviar
$mail->Password = 'secret'; //Su password
//Agregar destinatario

$mail->addReplyTo($correo, $nombre);
$mail->setFrom('micorreo@gmail.com', $asunto);
$mail->AddAddress('correos1@gmail.com');//A quien mandar email
$mail->addCC('correos2@gmail.com');
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  
$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 


    //Content
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML


$mail->Subject = 'MENSAJE DE FUTURO CLIENTE';
$mail->Body= $body;


if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Error al enviar email';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("MENSAJE ENVIADO CORRECTAMENTE");
    window.location.href="index.html";
    </script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Que tal yo sugiero que metas tu function en un try y asi controles la excepcion por si llega a fallar el envío de tu correo, y evites el if

```
try {
    //tu codigo
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Correo enviado';
    return true;
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Correo no enviado. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    return 0;
}
```

Y después retornes a las vista un true si se envío o un 0 si no y desde ahí hagas la lógica, así evitarías la vicualizacion de tu codigo.

Comment: aun no me sale! me sigue apareciendo todo mi codigo. :(

Answer (score 0):

Eso que ves es el "debug" por estar SMTPDebug en 2.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Comentá esa línea con doble barra `//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` o cambia el 2 por un 0.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: El que lo "lea" lo va a entender.